# What do we mean that a basis X is a subset of basis Y?

Tags: linear-algebra

So if we let $Y = \{y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5\}$
Then if we are saying that $X$ is a subset of $Y$ the do we mean that $X$ contains some or all of $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$?
Or can $X = {ay_1 + by_2 + cy_3, y_4}$ also be a subset of $Y$.

So I basically wanted to know that when we are saying 1 basis is a subset of another basis do we still follow the normal definition of subsets or something including the span of vectors in $Y$ also works for $X$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Normal definition, for sure.

Comment: So let us say that the basis of Y = {1, x, x^2, x^3} and X = { 1 + x^3 + x^2, x -1} then X is not a subset of Y, right?

Comment: No, it is not. You are just over-thinking about the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was really overthinking :) Really appreciate your help.